# Angular: Why is Child Route Loading Into Parent Outlet

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular 15 application with 2 levels of routing: Primary (`router-outlet` defined in `AppComponent`) and Person (`router-outlet` defined in `PersonMainComponent`).  The default component (`PersonMainComponent`) loads into the primary outlet fine.  when I click a link in `PersonMainComponent`, it should load a child component into the Person `router-outlet`.  However, it loads into the Primary `router outlet` instead.

AppComponent:

```html
  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
```

App routes:

```js
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'person', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ];
```

Person routes:

```js
 {path: 'person',
    children: [ 
        {path: '', component: PersonMainComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: PersonFieldDetailsComponent},  
    ]}
```

PersonMainComponent:

```html
<a routerLink="6">Should Load Into Child Outlet</a> 
Child Outlet: <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

PersonFieldDetailsComponent:

```html
<p>person-field-details works!</p>
```

What do I need to change to make `PersonFieldDetailsComponent` to load into the child outlet instead of the primary when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I had the person routes set up with the first route as a "componentless route" which is what was forcing the children to render into the parent router.  To fix it, I changed from the original person route definitions of this:

```js
{path: 'person',
    children: [ 
        {path: '', component: PersonMainComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: PersonFieldDetailsComponent},  
    ]}
```

to this:

```js
 {path: 'person',
  component: PersonMainComponent, //<-- added this
  children: [ 
    // {path: '', component: PersonMainComponent},   <-- removed this
    {path: ':id', component: PersonFieldDetailsComponent},  
  ]}
```